# Use of uninitialized value in sprintf

Tags: perl, warnings

I have a code like:

```
my ($line_1, $line2);
```

variables `$line_1` and `$line_2` are getting values from other function, that may be a **defined or undefined** value.

Now I am getting an error like `" Use of uninitialized value"`  evenafter i have initialised like

> $line_1 = " " if(!$line_1);

PLease help me in this

Comment: Undefined values give the "uninitialized" warning.

Comment: I have given like $a = " ", $b = " ". but this is also not working

Comment: You are doing something that is not correct. You should know that `$a` and `$b` are exceptions to the `strict` pragma, because they are built-ins used with the `sort` function. This may cause confusion when using `my` in a limited scope.

Comment: In short, if you want more help, you need to show more code, code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: edited the question, it was not exactly $a and $b

Comment: That does not exactly help. Your question is still impossible to answer with the information given. The warning tells us that you are using a value that is `undef`, and nothing else. Unless you show more code, no one can help you.

Comment: Also, you should never, ever, ever rename variables, or remove parts of warning/error messages. You should always cut & paste your information, so as to assure that you get all the details right. The details are what is important.

Comment: You didn't show what variables you used in `sprintf`. If you indeed did `$line_1 = " " if(!$line_1);` and nothing changed `$line_1` between then and the `sprintf`, the warning didn't come from using `$line_1`.

Comment: I am using it like sprintf(%s, $line_1) etc

Comment: Are you quoting your `sprintf` pattern? `%s` by itself is just a hash. (Which would throw an exception under `use strict` if it wasn't declared.)

Comment: it is like sprintf(qq|<file_name="%s">, $line_1)

Comment: @Kute It seems you are not understanding what I am telling you, so I guess what I am about to say might be futile. Your question cannot be answered like it is now. We do not have enough information to help you. You need to give more information, or your question should be closed as unanswerable due to lack of information. This might help further: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2):

To check for the definedness (whether it is `undef` or not) of a variable, use the [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) operator.

If you still get the warning, perl is right and your code is wrong. No magic here.